# missing parenthesis error in Mysql server

Tags: mysql

I am using the following code in MySQL server to get entries between 2 to 5 from table 'new_table' but I am receiving 'missing parenthesis' error, I have checked every aspect.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY salary ASC) AS row number
    FROM pact
)  as temp table name
WHERE rownumber IN (2,5)
```

Comment: MySQL *or* SQL Server, what you have will only work on the latter

Comment: tag says "mysql" but then your question text says "SQL server". Which is it? The code uses syntax that's specific to SQL Server and will never work in MySQL.

Comment: plus you can't have spaces in alias names e.g. "row number" or "temp table name". That's invalid on any SQL platform AFAIK.

Comment: so i just edited my ans and changed the tag from sql to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use space in alias

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY salary ASC) AS rownumber
    FROM pact
)  as temp_table_name
WHERE rownumber IN (2,5)
```

Comment: `templ table name` should also be converted to a no space version like `temp_table_name`

Answer (score 0):

if your using a MySql-Server there is nothing like ROW_NUMBER()
but you could try something like this (**UNTESTET**):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    @num := if(@type = type, @num + 1, 1) as rownumber
    FROM pact
    ORDER BY salary ASC
)  as temp_table_name
WHERE rownumber IN (2,5)
```